# How to render an iframe using third party script in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on ReactJS project and want to render an iframe which is rendering using third party script.

Kindly check the problem below:

**I have an component name add-data.js.**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';
import ogImage from '../../../../public/images/qcf-logo-whitebg.svg';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import ApplyNowNavbar from '../Header/ApplyNowHeader';
import ApplyNowFooter from '../Footer/ApplyNowFooter';

export default class ApplyNow extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar />
                <div id="iframe-container"></div> //iframe will be loadd inside this div
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**index.html main file**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
<script src="www.example.com/iframe-script.js"></script> <!--this file will load iframe in iframe-container div-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script src="../js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

this code works only when reload the page but I want to render iframe without reload the page but render ReactJS component.

Can anybody help me out how can I do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `<iframe src="www.example.com/iframe-script.js"/>`

Comment: it will not work, iframe only will render by third party script.

Comment: Do you have access to the third-party script? Meaning can you edit it's code? The reason why this is tricky is because the third-party script is probably trying to embed an iframe as soon as it loads, whereas your `React` component hasn't been created yet and the `div` element you're is not yet added to the DOM.

Comment: No I cannot edit third party script.

Comment: Yes may be you are right, but I have not found anything related to solution.